# How to display video using Django Detail view?

Tags: django, django-views

The following is my model.py

```
class VideoUpload(models.Model):
    user                = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    video               = models.FileField(null=False, upload_to='my_videos/videos/%Y/%m/%d/')
    video_thumbnail     = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to='my_videos/thumbnails/%Y/%m/%d/')
    video_title         = models.CharField(null=False, max_length = 120)
    slug                = models.CharField(null=False, max_length=50)
    date_uploaded       = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
```

the following is my views.py which has both listView and detailView

```
#listView

class VideoHome(ListView):
    model = VideoUpload
    template_name = 'videoTube/videoDetail.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["my_video_list"] = VideoUpload.objects.filter(user=self.request.user)
        context["other_video_list"] = VideoUpload.objects.exclude(user=self.request.user)
        return context

#detailView

class VideoDetailView(DetailView):
    model = VideoUpload
    template_name = 'videoDetail.html'
```

my url config is shown below

```
path('<pk>/', VideoDetailView.as_view(), name='video'),
```

Template

```
<body>
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="{{ videoupload.video.url }}" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</body>
```

learnerz is my project name inside learnerz/url.py i have included 'videoTube/'

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('videoTube/', include('videoTube.urls')),
]
```

Please let me know how to make the video display. Thank you in advance

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use a video tag, and access the video URL using the object. Place the code below into your HTML file for your detail view

```
    <video width="320" height="240" controls>
      <source src="{{ object.video.url }}" type="video/mp4">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
```

Comment: I changed as you have shown (the same is updated in the question as well) @X18PY, Getting the following error: Request URL: 127.0.0.1:8000/videoTube/1 Raised by: videoTube.views.VideoDetailView

Comment: I have updated the question with url patterens, so the url what i am using is  "127.0.0.1:8000/videoTube/1 "

Comment: 'videoTube/<pk>/',  here  videoTube/ is coming from url.py in the project directory, """ <pk>/', VideoDetailView.as_view(),""" this is inside my app directory

Comment: Output also showing  "No video upload found matching the query"

Comment: @AdarshaB.G The URLs under that message show what URLs were tried. You cut those out of the image.

Comment: No it is showing only this much, i have updated pls check, i will get the list of URLs you are pointing is when i send this url "127.0.0.1:8000/1"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/216898/discussion-between-x18py-and-adarsha-b-g).